# How to run a exe from the same folder as the application

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am working on MFC Application, i have a file that is run by the MFC application

```
LPWSTR appParams = A2W(final.c_str());
                    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo; //This is what we get as an [out] parameter
                    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo; //This is an [in] parameter
                    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
                    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof StartupInfo ; //Only compulsory field
                    if(CreateProcess(L"E:\\Setup\\vncviewer.exe",appParams,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo))
                    { 
                        WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
                        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
                        CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);

                    }
```

above is the code that run vncviewer.exe file on location e:\setup\, but i don't want this file to use static location, how can i add file in application folder, and also the same is added on setup file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to run the exe:

```
TCHAR szExeName[_MAX_PATH], drive[_MAX_DRIVE], dir[_MAX_DIR], fname[_MAX_FNAME], ext[_MAX_EXT];
GetModuleFileName(hInst, szExeName, _countof(szExeName));
_tsplitpath_s(szExeName, drive, dir, fname, ext);
_tmakepath(szExeName, drive, dir, L"vncviewer", L".exe");
if (CreateProcess(szExeName, ...
```